# Postgres - generate multiple rows and columns dynamically and join to an existing table

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I'm trying to convert an oracle query to postgres.

The Oracle query uses the below to generate dynamic table-like data:

```
SELECT ROWNUM TYPE_ID, regexp_substr('NED,SED,ZED,MED', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) TYPE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('NED,SED,ZED,MED', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL

Output:
TYPE_ID,TYPE
1,NED
2,SED
3,ZED
4,MED
```

Consider sample table:

```
create table details(
Title Varchar,
Misc Varchar
);

insert into details values ('DBA','5 years');
```

This is the whole query:

```
select /*ACC DATA*/ (case when ACC.TYPE_ID= 4 then null else
Title end)  Job_title,
ACC.* from DUAL,
(SELECT ROWNUM TYPE_ID, regexp_substr('NED,SED,ZED,MED', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) TYPE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('NED,SED,ZED,MED', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) ACC,
details

Output looks like this:
JOB_TITLE,TYPE_ID,TYPE
DBA,1,NED
DBA,2,SED
DBA,3,ZED
```

So effectively, the query is returning each row of the Details table thrice, with TYPE_ID as 1,2,3 and TYPE as NED,SED,ZED respectively.

How can this be achieved in Postgres 11.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered Postres does not have the usefull "connect by ...". But it does have other equally useful functions. In this case:  (See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b5a1bb2d7c5f192982c6cb4362664177))

- [regexp_split_to_table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)()
- [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html)() and unnest

Both of which will parse the string to individual elements. Unfortunately, neither provide an enumeration along with it, However, that it is easily gotten from the windowed function row_number. So, your Oracle statement becomes  (type is a reserved word in Postgres and would generate an error, so I changer to type_val.)

```
select row_number() over() type_id,type_val 
  from (select unnest(string_to_array('NED,SED,ZED,MED',',')) type_val ) sl
```

With that in place it is a simple step to cross join that with your details table getting what you want.

```
with split_list(type_id,type_val) as
     ( select row_number() over() type_id,type_val 
         from (select unnest(string_to_array('NED,SED,ZED,MED',',')) type_val ) sl 
     )         
select title, type_id, type_val
  from details
 cross join split_list
 where type_id != 4;
```